# Arduino String separated by comma to Array

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I am trying to do some Raw data handling of an IR Remote with Arduino.

```
unsigned int ArrayKey[68] = {30868,8900,4400,600,500,600,...,600};
irsend.sendRaw(ArrayKey,68,38);
```

Now I try to get a Raw IR Data via Serial, but there is a syntax problem:

readString is = 30868,8900,4400,600,500,600,1650,600,550,....

```
unsigned int ArrayKey[68] = {strtok(readString, ",")};
```

*error: cannot convert 'String' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char* strtok(char*, const char*)'*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot initialize it like that (non constant, non compatible etc.,), instead you can do it during run time

```
char *tmp;
int i = 0;
tmp = strtok(readString, ",");
while (tmp) {
   ArrayKey[i++] = atoi(tmp);
   tmp = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but now i got: cannot convert 'String' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'char* strtok(char*, const char*)'
in line: _tmp = strtok(readString, ",");_

Comment: I think your `readString` is a C++ `String`, if that is the case try using `&readString[0]` inside strtok.